# Hibernate cache issue?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, jboss5.x

I am using JPA with Hibernate behind, running inside a JBOSS 5.1.

I am getting a strange behaviour, because when I write some data through the EntityManager inside a transaction, I commit this transaction, and immediately after I start a new transaction to read this written data, the new data is not returned by the Query (but the old one), but I see the new data commited in the database (I see it through another proccess).

I can repeat this read as many times as I want (in debug mode in this same transaction), the new data will not be returned.

Then if I do a entityManager.clear(), the next read (in the same transaction) finally returns the data.

The funny part starts here: the same JBoss (a physical copy, librarys, config, everything) installed in another machine, pointing to the very same physical database works FINE (it gets the data without needing to clear the EM). So it has to be something related to the environment...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check `JBoss/server/default/deployers/ejb3.deployer/META-INF/persistence.properties` on both servers.

Unfortunately, by default it contains only `hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider` which is not transactional and should be replaced with `org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.JBossCacheRegionFactory` or `org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.JndiMultiplexedJBossCacheRegionFactory`.

See also

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClusteredJPAHibernateSecondLevelCachinginJBossAS5

http://www.mastertheboss.com/hibernate-cache/using-hibernate-second-level-cache-with-jboss-as-5-6-7

Comment: thank! well, both servers are exact copys, those files are the same... the only thing that changes is the physical machine and the JVM...

Comment: Not likely, i can stay for minutes holding the transaction on debug mode and throwing the query through the EM, it always returns old data, until I "clear" the EM, then the query returns the updated data... the whole JBoss is a clone of the one that works fine, both accessing the same physical DB... weird...